# Save 1D array in another 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I need to save an 1D array (histogram) from type double in a 2D array (represents parts of a picture).

Actually I have done this (simplified code):

```
private ArrayList<double[]>[][] calculateSignature(BufferedImage screenshot, int blocksizeX, int blocksizeY)
{
    ArrayList<double[]>[][] signature = new ArrayList[2][2];
    //!!!!! Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList[][] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<double[]>[][] !!!!!

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            signature[x][y] = calculateHistogram(screenshot.getSubimage(x * blocksizeX, y * blocksizeY, blocksizeX, blocksizeY));
        }
    }
    return signature;
}


private ArrayList<double[]> calculateHistogram(BufferedImage screenshot)
{
    double[] histogramRGB = new double[24];
    ...
    ArrayList<double[]> imageLUT = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    imageLUT.add(histogramRGB);

    return imageLUT;
}
```

This works but I think it isn´t a good implementation. Are there any improvements for that? Furthermore I get an error like this in the code comment above.

Comment: `HashMap` is a more efficient tool for these types of scenarios. Or just use plain array of object instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: But it isn´t possible to do something like this:

double [] value;
signature [0][0] = value;

Comment: "plain array of object" would definitely add to the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a `ArrayList` if you just add a single element - namely the 1D histogram. If you just need an 1D array in a 2D array as you say in your question, the `ArrayList` isn't necessary and you can simplify your code to:

```
private double[][][] calculateSignature(BufferedImage screenshot, int blocksizeX, int blocksizeY)
{
    double[][][] signature = new double[2][2][24];

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            signature[x][y] = calculateHistogram(screenshot.getSubimage(x * blocksizeX, y * blocksizeY, blocksizeX, blocksizeY));
        }
    }
    return signature;
}


private double[] calculateHistogram(BufferedImage screenshot)
{
    double[] histogramRGB = new double[24];
    ...
    return histogramRGB;
}
```

Comment: `double[][][] signature = new ArrayList[2][2][24];` ?

Comment: This works fine. But the problem in my opinion is that it isn´t transparent as the other. In the first case you can easy imagine that the picture is split into parts [0][0] [0][1] [1][0] [1][1] and every of the parts contains another array.

But how I can solve the warning in the first?

Comment: As I said in my answer using the `ArrayList` in your sample code is completely unnecessary as you only add a single element. Why don't you find my answer transparent? Having `double[2][2][24]` and a good code comment can also let the reader know about your image being split into 4 parts, each parts having 24 values (the histogram).